# How to return condition full fill object directly in typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I need to filter some array data and return only condition fulfill object. I try to like the below code. but `filterModel[0]` returns the first element of the filter array, not the condition full fill object. need some expert help to refactor this code, return `filterModel` ,which only this condition true `dInstance => dInstance.id === Id`.

```
export function getDModel(Id: string, data: DataModel): filterModel | undefined {
  const filterModel = data.valus?.filter(
    value => {
      const doseInstances = value.dInstances?.filter(dInstance => dInstance.id === Id);
      if (dInstances) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  );
  return filterModel && isNotNulAndNotEmpty(filterModel) ? filterModel[0] : undefined;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `.find()`?

Comment: so `getDModel` should return the first element in `data` that has atleast one `dInstance` whose `id` is same as `Id`, is that what you want?

Comment: @RameshReddy , last part is correct.. but should return not the first element, it should return the inner condition full fill element.

Comment: what should be the returned value is it an element in  `dInstances`?

Comment: value :)  (not first element of 'data.valus' array.

Comment: @uma but `value` is each element of `data.valus`...

Comment: yes, data.values = [ Object1 ,Object2, Object3 ,... ] -and value = Object1 ,object1 as Object1 = [  dInstances1 , dInstances2, dInstances3 .... ] , so, I pass ,dInstances1 = id as 3 , the take data.values , and again chack Object1  ,inside array .finnaly should return id find object.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227336/discussion-between-ramesh-reddy-and-uma).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) and [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to avoid things like `filterModel[0]` and other unnecessary checks

```
export function getDModel(Id: string, data: DataModel): filterModel | undefined {
    return data.valus.find(value => value.dInstances.some(dInstance => dInstance.id === Id));
}
```

Correct the incorrect property names if any because I'm not sure why it is `valus` instead of `values`.